# Incorrect output in a basic merge sort

Tags: c++, sorting

Tried to implement a merge sort, but getting the sort output incorrect...

For the input: 2 8 6 1 10 15 3 12 11
Getting the output as: 12 11 15 3 12 11 15 3 8

Not sure where the bug is...

Would appreciate any help. Thanks

```
template<class T>
void merge(T data[], int left, int right, T temp[])
{
    int mid = (left+right)/2;
    int l = left, r= mid+1, t=0;

    while(l <= mid && r <= right)
    {
        if(data[l] < data[r])
            temp[t++] = data[l++];
        else
            temp[t++] = data[r++];

    }

    while(l <= mid)
        temp[t++] = data[l++];

    while(r <= right)
        temp[t++] = data[r++];

    //copy it back
    for(int i=0; i<(right-left+1); i++)
        data[i] = temp[i];

}

template<class T>
void merge_helper(T data[], int first, int last, T temp[])
{
    if(first < last)
    {
        int mid = (first+last)/2;
        merge_helper(data, first, mid, temp);
        merge_helper(data, mid+1, last, temp);
        merge(data, first, last, temp);

    }

}


// merge sort

template<class T>
void mergesort(T data[], int size)
{
    T *temp = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T)*size);
    merge_helper(data, 0, size-1, temp);
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has not shown any debugging effort.

Comment: Why is this tagged as C when it is C++?

Answer (score 3):

```
//copy it back
for(int i=0; i<(right-left+1); i++)
 data[i] = temp[i];
```

possible problem here when you are copying it back into the original array, you always start from zero, you must copy it back from the left element to the right element.

try this

```
for(int i = left,k=0; i<=right;i++,k++)
data[i] = temp[k];
```

Comment: or `for(int i=0; i<(right-left+1); i++)
 data[i + left] = temp[i];`